# XSD validation: Element Value should be sum of 2 other Elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

```
<xml>
   <root>
     <courses>
         <course>
             <ceu>2000</ceu>
             <first_year>1000</first_year>
             <second_year>1000</first_year>
         </course>
     </courses>
   </root>
```

How do I add XSD validation so that the element CEU's value is always equal to the sum of first_year and second_year values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.

### XSD 1.1

This XML file will be valid:

```
<course>
  <ceu>3000</ceu>
  <first_year>1000</first_year>
  <second_year>2000</second_year>
</course>
```

With this XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="course">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ceu" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        <xs:element name="first_year" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        <xs:element name="second_year" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="ceu = first_year + second_year"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But this XML:

```
<course>
  <ceu>4000</ceu>
  <first_year>1000</first_year>
  <second_year>2000</second_year>
</course>
```

Will violate the assertion and result in an error message such as the following:

> [cvc-assertion](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-assertion): Assertion evaluation ('ceu = first_year +
>   second_year') for element 'course' on schema type '#AnonType_course'
>   did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `xsd 1.1`, you can use `xs:assert` :

```
<xs:element name="course">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ceu" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="first_year" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="second_year" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="ceu = sum((first_year,second_year))"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```